# What is the best way to minimize recalibration time with the google tango?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, google-project-tango

What is the best way to minimize recalibration time with the google device?  Is it best to have landmarks in the environment to point to in the room? What kinds of tricks can I use to make the most optimal ADF file, in order to calibrate (and re-calibrate) with the fastest possible startup time?

Answer (score 1):

In short, recorded an Area Description File (ADF) with more features.

Also, by re-calibrate, I think you meant relocalization, which is the process of getting Tango to find out the origin for the ADF and shift its position.

A detailed ADF will have more visual features for the system to "look at", so that it will be easier for the system to know where it is within the ADF. When you record an ADF, make sure the device observes all the visual features from all direction. For example, if you are recording a hallway, make sure you walk from both direction, so the device see it from both side. Recording an ADF is a tricky process, I always think it like a painting process, like you have a spray to paint the walls, once the "spray" covered all of the walls, then you have recorded all of the features to the ADF..